# Is a factorial-primorial mesh divisible by the factorial infinitely often?

Tags: number-theory

### Question

Suppose the factorial and primorial functions conceived a baby through the act of addition and called it $n!\#$, and it looked like this:

$$n!\# = \prod_{i=1}^n (p_i + i) = (2 + 1)(3 + 2)(5 + 3)(7 + 4) \dots (p_n + n)$$

Does it happen infinitely often that the factorial divides this function, i.e. are there infinite integer solutions to:

$$\dfrac{n!\#}{n!}$$

#### Background

The factorial function $n!$ is well known and is given by:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n i = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \dots n$$

The marginally less well known primorial function $p_n\#$ is given by:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n p_i = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times \dots p_n$$

where $p_i$ is the $i^{th}$ prime.

The function defined above is catalogued in the OEIS under the following link: [OEIS reference](https://oeis.org/search?q=A093570%20-id:A093570). However there is no reference to divisibility by $n!$ there.

#### What I know so far

Here are the first few values I've computed for $n!\#$:

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
n & n! & n!\# & \textrm{divides?} \\ 
\hline
1 & 1 & 3 & \textrm{Yes} \\ 
2 & 2 & 15 & \textrm{No} \\ 
3 & 6 & 120 & \textrm{Yes}\\ 
4 & 24 & 1320 & \textrm{Yes} \\
5 & 120 & 21120 & \textrm{Yes} \\
6 & 720 & 401280 & \textrm{No} \\
7 & 5040 & 9630720 & \textrm{No} \\
\end{array}$

### My Intuition

I'm of two minds as to the truth of this statement, and I don't have enough experience with numbers to judge either way, so I'm on the fence for now. Here are my two basic arguments, which are far from rigorous.

**Argument for:** The primes are randomly scattered, whereas the sequence $1, 2, 3, \dots, n$ isn't. So adding $p_n + n$ should preserve the randomness that was there in the primes in the first place. By randomness, I mean there should be no preference shown for particular prime factors over others. Now, since $n\#!$ grows much faster than $n!$, it should eventually start sweeping up all the primes in $n!$. Perhaps there is even some $N$ such that that divisibility of $n!\#$ by $n!$ is true for all $n > N$, but this is quite strong and I'm not so sure.

**Argument against:** On the other hand, what throws doubt on the conjecture is that because $n\#!$ grows so fast, perhaps it grows *too* fast, and *misses* lots of little primes that are bundling up in $n!$. In other words, perhaps there is a point $N$ such that that divisibility of $n!\#$ by $n!$ is **false** for all $n > N$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a proof, but here is some relevant numerical evidence for the conjecture that $n=1,3,4,5$ are the only times (not counting $n=0$) this fraction is an integer.

Firstly, it's the only solution for $n$ up to $15000$. (All [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) code below.)

More importantly, the number of prime factors in the denominator that are not cancelled out (counted with multiplicity so that $20=2^2*5$ has $3$ prime factors) appears to grow roughly linearly with $n$, yet it would have to drop to $0$ for the fraction to be an integer.

Here is an unconvincing plot for $0\le n<100$:
[image: plot up to 99]

Here is a plot for $0\le n\le7000$ with the line $y=(0.0868166)x+27$ drawn on top:[image: plot up to 7000]

---

```
(*Mathematica Code*)

f[0]=1;
f[n_]:=f[n]=f[n-1]*(Prime[n]+n);

Print[Table[ If[IntegerQ[f[n]/(n!)], n, Nothing], {n, 0, 15000}]];

countprimes[n_] := countprimes[n] = -Total[Transpose[Select[FactorInteger[f[n]/(n!)], Function[x, 0 > x[[2]] ] ]][[2]]];

Print[ListPlot[Table[{n, If[n==0||n==1||n==3||n==4||n==5,0,countprimes[n]]}, {n, 0, 99}]]];

m=Table[{n, If[n==0||n==1||n==3||n==4||n==5,0,countprimes[n]]}, {n, 0, 7000}];

Print[LinearModelFit[m, x, x]];

Show[ListPlot[m], Plot[27 + 0.0868166 x, {x, 0, 7000}, PlotStyle -> Orange]]
```

Comment: One of us did something wrong since I also found $n=11, 12$!  I don't see anything wrong with your code at first glance.

Comment: @DanBrumleve For $n=11$, the denominator is divisible by $25$ but the numerator is $(2+1)(3+2)(5+3)(7+4)(11+5)(13+6)(17+7)(19+8)(23+9)(29+10)(31+11)=3*5*8*11*16*19*24*27*32*39*42$, which only has one factor of $5$. For $n=12$ there's another factor of $37+12$ which still doesn't give a $5$.

Comment: aaand it turns out my program has a memory initialization bug that's causing it to give incorrect results on my system starting at $n=9$.

Comment: Oops forgot about the bounty over the Christmas period! Should have been (+50). thanks for the hard work :)

Answer (score 1):

Conjecture: for all prime $q$, $q$ divides $p_n + n$ infinitely often.  We know by Dirichlet's theorem that there are an infinite number of primes in any arithmetic progression, $p_n = a \cdot q + b$ with $a$ free and $0 \lt b \lt q$, and there is no apparent relationship between $b$ and $n$.  But this looks like it might be very difficult to prove.

This is equivalent to: for all $k$, there exists an $n$ such that $\frac{ n!\# }{k!}$ is an integer; a much weaker version of your problem, so proving the affirmative will be at least as hard.

If it is not true that $n!$ divides $n!\#$ infinitely often, we should first be able to prove that infinitely often $n!$ does *not* divide $n!\#$ and so far I'm unable to do that either.  Heuristically, the $n$ terms of $n!\#$ are random $\text{mod} \space n$, so we should expect a $(1 - \frac{1}{n})^n \rightarrow \frac{1}{e}$ probability that none of them are divisible by $n$, and when $n$ is prime this means at least a $\frac{1}{e}$ chance that $n!$ does not divide $n!\#$.  I think this can be turned into a heuristic argument against your original statement.

I wrote [a program](http://pastebin.com/WkLxkqQi) to check the condition.  The only values I found where $n! \space \vert \space n!\#$ and $n \lt 3000$ are $n = 1, 3, 4, 5$.  That means the answer is likely "no", to learn more about why it might be interesting to study the resulting denominator at each stage.

I also tried it with [primorial instead of factorial](http://pastebin.com/xMDe7Xk8) in the denominator, I found $n = 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16$ and no others less than $3000$.  It's not just the multiplicity of smaller primes in the denominator that's causing divisibility to fail, the introduction of new primes seems to be enough.

I'll update this answer if I make any more progress.

Comment: Bravo sir. Some comments: I think you may be slightly off with Dirichlet's theorem- $gcd(b, q) = 1$ rather than $0 < b < q$, no? Other than that, I really like your idea with $e$. If we test again for divisibility by $n-1, n-2$ and so on, we should get geometric shrinking... although I worry about dependent probabilities.

Comment: Also, I applaud the use of programs. Another thing that would be interesting to know would be how many "crossing points" are there, where divisibility goes from true to false or vice versa. If these seem to thin out, then it will strengthen the argument against. Finally, when you say you tried primorial instead of factorial- you mean $n\#$ rather than $p_n\#$? There's a significant difference. The latter is a linked question that I think is false: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576851/is-a-factorial-primorial-mesh-ever-divisible-by-the-primorial?lq=1.

Comment: For prime $q$ those conditions are the same.  Also, the last program I tried is with $n\#$ in the denominator.

Comment: Duh, obviously $q$ is a prime, my brain slows down sometimes and hedgehogs pass it by. Yes, interesting, $n\#$ in the denominator would give more positive results as $n\#$ always divides $n!$. I am very surprised that the program found so few positive results. It seems $n!\#$ is skipping over early primes. The question is, does it eventually "strike gold" and fill them in in time to catch up with $n\#$, or are there always gaps? I still think it will eventually catch up, infinitely often.

Comment: Checking my answer against Mark S.'s revealed some bugs in my code producing false positives, which I've now corrected in this answer.  (I also deleted my last comment that had some calculations based on the buggy code).